# How to see docker server content in browser

Tags: docker

install `docker toolbox` in `win7 64bit`

my code:

```
docker run --name web -d -p 8000:8000 richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
```

I can't see any result in chrome browser.

reinstall `docker toolbox` && reboot && disable firewall did not help.

192.168.99.100:8000
172.17.0.2:8000
localhost:8000

```
docker inspect web | grep IPAddress
```

show:

```
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

run:

```
$ docker-machine ls
```

show:

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL      SWARM   DO
CKER        ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1
8.06.1-ce
```

run:

```
$ docker ps
```

show:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  
CREATED
       STATUS              PORTS
NAMES
65b815ffa17c        richarvey/nginx-php-fpm   "docker-php-entrypoi"   4 hours ag
o         Up 4 hours          80/tcp, 443/tcp, 9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
web
```

---

[image]

---

**update**

```
docker run --name web -d -p 8000:80 richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
```

http://192.168.99.100:8000/  <-- only this one work!
http://172.17.0.2:8000/
http://localhost:8000/

Inside docker,

1. first off check if nginx is running.
2. see which process is using port 80

---

```
bash-4.4# ps aux | grep nginx
   14 root      0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon off; error_
log /dev/stderr info;
   15 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   16 nginx     0:00 php-fpm: pool www
   17 nginx     0:00 php-fpm: pool www
   18 nginx     0:00 php-fpm: pool www
   29 root      0:00 grep nginx
bash-4.4# netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
14/stderr info;
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
14/stderr info;
bash-4.4#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you use publishes NGinx port at its port 80. So, if you want it at your public port 8000, you should run the container with:

```
docker run --name web -d -p 8000:80 richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
```

**Edit:** Alternatively (only with Docker on Linux), you can access to container's private IP (taken from `docker inspect web`) at port 80 with your browser: http://172.17.0.2

Comment: I think the Docker-internal IP addresses are unreachable if you're using Docker Toolbox.  They're unreachable in a lot of interesting cases and you should avoid looking for or using them.  You need the `docker-machine ip` address, usually 192.168.99.100, as the "host".

Comment: only `docker-machine ip` (192.168.99.100) work. `docker inspect conainter-id | grep IPAddress` (172.17.0.2) (Docker-internal IP?) doesn't work.